# Searching worksheets to return True or False based on value

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have 2 excel worksheets. The first worksheet has 1 column representing route numbers and 4 columns representing values at 4 stops (see below)

[image]

The second worksheet has columns representing route numbers, latitude, longitude and stop numbers (see below).

[image]

I want to use the route numbers and stop numbers in the second worksheet to search the matching cell in the first worksheet and return a TRUE or FALSE as to whether the value is 0.

The result using my two examples would look as shown below.

[image]

What function would I need to perform this search and return?

Comment: Are the column headers in the first worksheet text values as *Stop1, Stop2, etc.* or are they numbers formatted as `"Stop"0`?

Comment: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/two-way-lookup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your first sheet is Sheet1, you could use the following formula:

```
=vlookup($a2,sheet1!$A$2:$E$6,match("Stop"&$d2,sheet1!$a$1:$e$1,0),0)=0
```

The match will retrieve the column corresponding to your Stop, and the vlookup will match the row corresponding to your route.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it wasn't working as stated. I changed it to `=vlookup($a2,sheet1!$A$2:$E$6,match("Stop"&$d2,sheet1!$a$1:$e$1,0),0)=0` and it is working perfectly.

Comment: Correct, first row was #2. I adjusted.